# поднятие и выбрасывание объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго времени суток, друзья. У меня проблема, я уже пробовал несколько решений ни один не подходит.

Мне нужно, чтобы, когда игрок заходил в триггер снежка, мог по нажатию UI кнопки переместить снежок в указанную точку и сохранять своё местоположение в этой точке ** (эти снежки разбросаны по карте, они идентичны и нужно чтобы перемещался тот в чьём триггере находится игрок)**.

Так же по этой же кнопке (или можно создать вторую кнопку) выбрасывать данный префаб снежка

Я брал несколько вариантов, но они не работают так как мне надо, жду c# скрипт или натолкните на решение

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не могу оставить комментарий из-за репутации. Я не силен в Unity, но мой совет - если мы хотим переместить какой-то предмет в игре, то должны менять его координаты. Тоже самое здесь, при нажатии на условный Button цепляем первый попавшийся объект, который находится в зоне коллайдера. То есть его координаты должны быть относительно игрока, а не игрового мира.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    
}
```

P.S. А вообще для взаимодействие с игровым миром используют лучи